# quote numeric fields in R

Tags: r, csv

I am having trouble finding the correct way to quote
every field type when using any of the write csv functions.

I have noticed that `write.csv()` does not have a `quote=`
argument. And with `write_csv()`, the `quote="all"` argument
does not quote numeric fields.

Do I need to convert numeric fields to character to get the
quotes or am I not finding the argument needed like with Python's
`quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`?

Comment: `write.table` has a `quote=` argument however, and `write.csv` calls `write.table` (type `write.csv` at the command line and you can see this). It doesn't look like `write.csv` will quote numeric fields either, unless you convert them to character first: `write.csv(data.frame(a=c(1.2,2.3,3.4),b=c(10,11,12),c=letters[1:3]),quote=1:3)`

Comment: If the data frame is made up of numeric and character columns and has at least one character column then converting it to matrix will coerce it all to character so using the example in the prior comment `DF <- data.frame(a = c(1.2,2.3,3.4), b = c(10,11,12), c = letters[1:3]); 
write.csv(as.matrix(DF), stdout(), quote = TRUE)` will have all fields quoted.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck `as.matrix(df)` quoted the numeric fields. Thank you for that answer.